# Reasons for using a Bag in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, bag

I am currently studying about Algorithms & Data Structures and while I was reading over the Book of Algorithms 4th edition, I discovered the `Bag` data-structure together with the `Stack` and `Queue`.
After reading the the explanation of it, it is still unclear to me why would I prefer using a `Bag` (which has no `remove()` method) over other data-structures such as `Stack`, `Queue`, `LinkedList` or a `Set`?
As far as I can understand from the Book, the implementation of a `Bag`, is the same as for a `Stack`, just replacing the name of `push()` to `add()` and remove the `pop()` method.

So the idea of a `Bag` is basically having the ability to collect items and then iterate through the collected items, check if a bag is empty and find the number of items in it.
But under which circumstances I would better using a `Bag` over one of the mentioned above Collections? And why a `Bag` doesn't have a `remove()` method basically? is there a specific reason for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Stack` is ADT of the collection of elements with specific remove order = LIFO (last-in-first-out), allows duplicates,

`Queue` is ADT of the collection of elements with specific remove order = FIFO (first-in-first-out), allows duplicates,

`LinkedList` is implementation of the list,

`Set` is ADT of the collection of elements which disallows duplicates,

`Bag` is ADT of the collection of elements which allows duplicates.

In general, anything that holds an elements is `Collection`.
Any collection which allows duplicates is `Bag`, otherwise it is `Set`.
Any bag which access elements via index is `List`. 
Bag which appends new element after the last one and has a method to remove element from the head (first index) is `Queue`.
Bag which appends new element after the last one and has a method to remove element from the tail (last index) is `Stack`.

Example: In Java, [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is a collection, bag, list, queue and also you can work with it as it was a stack since it support stack operations (`add`~`addLast`~`push`, `peekLast`, `removeLast`~`pop`), so you can call it also stack. The reason, why it does not implement [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) interface is, that `peek` method is reserved by [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) implementation which retrieves the head of the list (first element). Therefore in case of [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), the "stack methods" are derived from [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html).

Whether `Bag` contains `remove(Object)` or not may depend on the implementation e. g. you can implement your own `Bag` type which supports this operation. Also you can implement `get(int)` operation to access object on specified index. Time complexity of the `get(int)` would depend on your implementation e. g. one can implement `Bag` via linked-list so the complexity would be at average O(n/2), other one via resizable array (array-list) with direct access to the element via index, so the complexity would be O(1).

But the main idea of the `Bag` is, that it allows duplicates and iteration through this collection. Whether it supports another useful operations depends on implementator's design decision.

Which one of the collection type to use dependes on your needs, if duplicates are not desired, you would use `Set` instead of `Bag`. Moreover, if you care about remove order you would pick `Stack` or `Queue` which are basically `Bags` with specific remove order. You can think of `Bag` as super-type of the `Stack` and `Queue` which extends its api by specific operations.

Most of the time, you just need to collect objects and process them in some way (iteration + element processing). So you will use the most simple `Bag` implementation which is one directional linked-list.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the characteristics of each one of them, but I'm already aware to that information and what each ADT is able to do, but my question is when does a `Bag` comes more handy over other ADT's?

Comment: @TalBuaron, think of it at a list where you don't care what position element is in, but you specifically want to allow duplicate elements.

Comment: @TalBuaron use Bag when you do not care whether the collection is FIFO or FILO.  This becomes useful when performance is a concern as it will let you pick an implementation of a Bag that has different BigO characteristics to either Stack or Queue.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov , so `Bag` is the only Collection/Data Structure which allows duplicates and no order of insertion? that's interseting

Comment: Thank you for your answer @matoni, the information you gave definitely helped me understand the Bag.

Comment: What is ADT? 

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala ADT stands for Abstract Data Type

Answer (score 0):

`Bag` is an unordered collection of values that may have duplicates. When comparing a stack to a bag, the first difference is that for stacks,
order matters.

Bag only supports the `add` and `iterate` operations. You cannot remove items from a bag-it’s possible to remove elements from a stack.-. After checking if the container is actually empty, clients can iterate through its elements; since the actual order is unspecified by definition, clients must not rely on it.

Bags are useful when you need to collect objects and process them as a whole set rather than individually. For example, you could collect samples and then, later, compute statistics on them, such as average or standard deviation—the order is
irrelevant in that case.

in terms of priority queues, a bag is  a Priority queue for which element
removal (top()-Returns and extracts the element with the highest priority. ) is disabled. Priority Queue api has, `top`, `peek`,`insert`,`remove` and `update` methods. it’s possible to peek one element at a time, and the
priority of each element is given by a random number from a uniform distribution. Priorities also change at every iteration.